# Should we not throw exception in test automation using selenium?

Tags: exception, timeout

In any test suite framework is it recommended to throw exception, as these will stop execution of script and do not continue suite.

In most of the user actions I am only logging and continuing execution. In some cases we can't avoid InterruptedException which Intellij editor recommends and we cNt get away with that, is it good to use this exception compared to Exception class?

I am trying all with junit, Java cucumber and selenium.

Also only when I observe timeout exception, the execution doesn't continue and totaly fails further test scripts. This is serious issue compared to all others. Any help or explanation appreciated.

Tried checking package of timeoutException

These 2 behaviours can someone explain.

Comment: This isn't really a question that can be answered on SO.  You may want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Though it also seems you're extremely novice at Java and you can not yet distinguish between declared and thrown exceptions. You may want to consider following a introductory course to Java first.